# jquery.RemoveClass - Removing class by not refering id

Tags: jquery, css, removeclass

[image]

I am looking for the quick fix for removing the class 'checked' in the lower most level. `$('#bannerGeography tr td .allTR .option-group div.checkbox').RemoveClass('checked');`

Did not seem to work. Can you please help

Comment: use removeClass() not RemoveClass();

Comment: and next time, post your actual HTML...not an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `removeClass`(Notice `r`) and not `RemoveClass`:

```
$('#bannerGeography tr td .allTR .option-group div.checkbox').removeClass('checked');
//                                                            ^
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

> Remove a single class, multiple classes, or all classes from each element in the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

use *removeClass()* instedad of *RemoveClass()*

```
$('#bannerGeography div.checkbox').removeClass('checked');
```

NOTE: In your DOM structure **TR** not having any children of  **.allTR** so you have to use `find()` selector  like above or use this `$('#bannerGeography').find('div.checkbox').removeClass('checked');`